# Rewrite $u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u_t+au = 0$ as a $2 \times 2$ first order system

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

How can we write the damped wave equation
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u_t+au = 0,$$
with $a>0$, as a linear first-order system?

Note that we can write 
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}+u_t = 0$$
as 
$$
w_t = Aw_x + Bw, 
$$
where 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$
by setting $w= (u_x,u_t)^T$.

How can we deal with the additional $au$ term?

Comment: Do you mean $w_t=Aw_x+Bw$?

Comment: @timur Yes. Thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to introduce the variables $v=u_t$ and $w=u_x$ to write
$$
\begin{split}
u_t&=v,\\
v_t&=w_x-au-v,\\
w_t&=v_x.
\end{split}
$$
It is of the form
$$
U_t=AU_x+BU,
$$
with
$U=(u,v,w)^T=(u,u_t,u_x)^T$, and constant matrices $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks. How do you write it in matrix form as in the question above?

Comment: @Lao: You tell me first how you wrote yours involving $w$.

Comment: I've edited my question to answer the question in your comment. Note, however, that, in my example, the "damping term" is $u_t$ (which is also the second component of the vector $w$). In the case asked in the question. you also have $au$, which complicates things.

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I see the confusion. Let me rephrase the question: is there a way to have it written as a $2 \times 2$ system?

Comment: Not fair that you changed the question after I answered the original question.